# Aliasing names for members in struct template

Tags: c++, stl

I use my template in code that works with math:

```
template <typename T> 
struct range {
    T min, max;
};
```

Now I realized that I need the same for iterators, but to make code more readable I need the other names for the fields. I can do this way:

```
template <typename T> 
struct iterators_range {
    T lower, upper;
};
```

but I want to stay with the same short name for the template. The same will be with alternative namespace.

First idea is to alias somehow these names. Is it possible in the modern C++?

Of course, naïve solution

```
template <typename T> 
struct range {
    T min, max;
    T& lower = min;
    T& upper = max;
};
```

doesn’t work, since it creates two references (pointers) and consumes memory.

I want to keep things simple and therefore don't want to use accessor methods (accessor member functions) (don't want excessive brackets in the client code.

Is there something better to reuse the same structure?

**Update**

An update since people asking why I don't like to use accessor methods (accessor member functions).

I don't like neither ugly code like:

```
range r;
r.setLower(value);
```

nor confusing code like:

```
range r;
r.lower()=value;
```

and key is usage in formulas which have their own brackets, for example:

```
range r;
float result = 1.0f/(1.0f - input/(r.min()-r.max()));
```

is much worse than

```
range r;
float result = 1.0f/(1.0f - input/(r.min-r.max));
```

imagine what would be if the formula has more brackets.

Comment: It is possible in modern C++, but it involves accessor methods, which you pre-emptively nixed. And I'm the last person to suggest a macro.

Comment: I would use member functions, but I presume that's what you mean by "accessor methods".  I'm not sure why you don't find those "simple".

Comment: @Eljay, I don't see any way a macro could work since it won't have information about the object; so it will replace all max/min in code to all lower/upper. So, no way even to suggest. :)

Comment: @DrewDormann, yes, you are correct, I put the clarification in the question, I mean member functions, not sure why "method" word doesn't work for you in this case. "Method" is a function in class/structure. "Accessor" the standard term, as well, for function which serves for access to internal data only. Anyway, the reason is stated in the question: I want to avoid excessive brackets in the client code. Just imagine if they are in complex formulas with its own brackets. And I don't like function syntax when I need just a variable; this is confusing.

Comment: Why are alternate names more readable? Seems like it would allow for more confusion if two names were equal and equivalent.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, because of the context. In case I use this for values like parameters, limits, random number generators initializers, etc. min and max are intuitive, short and make code readable in terms of math terms - min and max; they are everywhere; they mean that these are min and max _values_. When I work with iterators I need other terms, stressing that these are not values, but _iterators_ to them - lower and upper (just remember names of std::lower_bound and std::upper_bound). I want to be consistent.

Comment: Just in case you were wondering, having `r.lower()=value;` return a mutable reference like that is not considered "confusing" in C++, it's pretty common. `r.setLower(value);` us a Java-ism, and is not typically considered normal in C++. The extra parentheses to call the accessors isn't all that meaningful; the Java-style completely reorders operations (`b.x + c.x` with primitives becomes `b.x.add(c.x)` with non-primitives), but self-closing parens as in your example aren't particularly hard to read through, it's only when it introduces more *nesting* of parens that you have readability issues.

Comment: @DamirTenishev: So you want to stress they're not the same, but you also want them equal and equivalent? That's where I'm confused. If you want to avoid confusion, then have one version of the class specifically for iterators with the iterator names, and one version for non-iterators with the non-iterator names, and no one can be confused. As is, your proposed design would have `some_range.max - some_range.min` work whether you use (some types of) iterators or raw values, and would get results with different logical meaning (the range of values for values, the distance for iterators).

Comment: If you want to stress the difference, split the types so mistakes like that can't happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible using [anonymous unions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union#Anonymous_unions):

```cpp
template <typename T> 
struct range {
    union { T min, lower; };
    union { T max, upper; };
};
```

You can have as many names for the same data member as you want.
This solution assumes that `T` is a trivial type though. If it's non-trivial like `std::string`, you would need to manage the lifetime of each `union` manually, and that would be extra work.

---

*Note: Technically speaking, each `union` is a data member and each union has multiple members. This distinction isn't relevant though, since C++ allows accessing inactive union members of the same type. For all intents and purposes, `T min, lower` works like having multiple names for the same member.*

Comment: *C++ allows accessing inactive union members of the same type*  How "same" same do they have to be?  Are these two `union { signed s; unsigned u; }` same enough?

Comment: @Eljay you can access inactive members if they are part of the [common initial sequence](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem.general#def:common_initial_sequence) of two `struct`s. This requires them to have [layout-compatible](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#def:type,layout-compatible) members, among other properties. Oddly enough, the current wording does not support reading an inactive union member that is not a `struct`, but simply the same type. I suspect this may be a wording bug.